# No if, quando o usuário coloca outro estado que não está especificado, ao invés de entrar no else, ele entra no if e continua o código normalmente

Tags: python, if, else

O código está assim:

```
est = input('Qual estado reside atualmente? ')  
if est == 'São Paulo' or 'SP' or 'sao paulo' or 'São paulo':  
    email = input('Digite o seu e-mail: ')   
    tel = input('Digite o seu celular pessoal: ')  
    tel2 = input('Digite seu telefone comercial ou residencial: ')  
else:  
    print('Não atendemos na sua localidade!')  
    exit()
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, o problema está acontecendo na condição do `if`. É necessário que você adicione `est ==`  antes de todas as possibilidades:

```py
if est == 'São Paulo' or est == 'SP' or est == 'sao paulo' or est == 'São paulo':
```

Alterando desta forma irá entrar no `if` corretamente.

Answer (score -1):

Poderia escrever as condições do if da mesma maneira que escreveu o primeiro condicional. Segue o exemplo:

```
if est == 'São Paulo' or  est == 'SP' or  est == 'sao paulo' or  est == 'São paulo':
```

Estou destacando apenas o trecho do if, como poderia ser re-escrito de uma maneira que possa ser avaliado corretamente.

Em seu código como o condicional está escrito nesta forma:

```
if est == 'São Paulo' or 'SP':
```

Então a comparação do `if` avalia o valor literal `'SP'`.

Como qualquer string diferente do valor vazio `""` possui o valor de retorno `true`, o seu condicional sempre é avaliado como verdadeiro.